# Good Literature on effect sizes

Tags: effect-size

reporting effect sizes is pretty common nowadays, but I couldn't yet find any good book that compares different effect sizes values (d, g, r, etc.). I know the article by Rosnow and Rosenthal (2009), but they have no examples of computation. For me sometimes it's not clear, which standard deviation or standard error is used and what range the effect size can take.

To be more specific. Right now I want to report results of independent as wel as dependent sample t-tests. I know r for effect sizes, but I would like to compute Cohen's d for example. How do I do it? what is the range of it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You'll find what you need in books on meta-analysis.

One short and practical guide that I've found helpful is an inexpensive book by Fredric Wolf from 1986, [Meta-Analysis:  Quantitative Methods for Research Synthesis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0803927568).

For greater detail and rigor, try the book by [Gene Glass, Barry McGaw and Mary Lee Smith](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0803916337).
And there's an extensive list of meta-analysis books [here](http://www.um.es/metaanalysis/texts.php).